# How to know if a class is inherited from another class in PHP?

Tags: php

I only have the class string not a object. And to `new` a new object might not be the best solution.

Comment: maybe this helps? http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.issubclassof.php

Answer (score 2):

The [class_parents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php) function will return an array containing the names of all classes in the inheritance tree, and will work by passing it a class name or an instance.

You can then simply check the results from that returned array

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function [`is_subclass_of`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) can operate using two strings as the parameters. You shouldn't need to instantiate any objects to test this, or use Reflection, which is a fairly expensive operation (as suggested in the accepted answer of the duplicate).

```
class foo {}
class bar extends  foo {}

is_subclass_of('bar', 'foo'); // true
```

This will also work to test if a class implements an interface.